# Cheapest scheduled summer public transport from Vancouver to Whistler and back?

Tags: public-transport, budget, vancouver, whistler

I'd like to head up to Whistler to do some paddleboarding and hiking.  However, I don't have a car.  I could use the car co-ops, or there may well just be a cheap and easy bus, train or plane.

So to that end, what's the cheapest public transport way to get to the town of Whistler from Vancouver?  I want scheduled options, as I'd need to be there at a particular time (yet to be determined).  So hitchhiking doesn't work in this case :/

Comment: I guess this is for soon, rather than the winter? (I gather there are a wider range of options available during the ski season)

Comment: Yup, paddleboarding and hiking aren't as easy in the winter, what with the frozen lakes and all ;)  I'll update the question though.

Comment: hey, are you going to accept an answer or are you waiting for a bus under $10 round-trip? because under $15 one-way I am not even sure carpooling is cheaper.

Comment: I've only lived here a few months, so I'm still new to the area.  I'd never even heard of Pacific Coach.  I hadn't had any responses, so I used a bounty. That's what they're there for.

Comment: yes, and the button to accept an answer is also here to accept an answer. It's not a big deal but I spend time searching the web so I also appreciate consideration from the askers. btw, accepting ananswer does not remove the bounty effect (attention from everyone): http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty. If someone knows something cheaper, he can still add it and you can accept his answer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems [Greyhound](http://www.greyhound.ca/) is operating a bus between Vancouver and Whistler, for 30 dollars max one way. The web fare is $20 and if you book at least 3 weeks in advance, it can be as low as **$15** .

Answer (score 6):

Best solution: Greyhound Bus for $40 return.

I've spent about 2 hours researching this and bus is definitely your cheapest option. Rail, Plane and Car rental are going to be more expensive.

Looks tough to get any kind of public transport outside of the ski season. Most buses don't seem to be running.

EDIT: In my original answer I didn't have Greyhound because their website was not showing any buses travelling in the next couple of months. It seems this was a bug rather than a lack of services running. So this is now your cheapest option. Thanks to @vince for posting his answer I had another look.

[Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.ca/), $40 return.

Only other bus found:
[Pacific Coach](http://www.pacificcoach.com/): $88 return:

If you're lucky, you'll find a ride through a ride-sharing service like zimride, which would probably halve the cost, [this ride for example is $20 one way](http://www.zimride.com/search?s=Vancouver,%20BC&e=Whistler&date=08/25/2012):